# What was the "most copied comment" with a score of 938?

Tags: discussion, comments, blog

I was reading the blog article [*How often do people actually copy and paste from Stack Overflow? Now we know*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/) and there was a section at the bottom (<kbd>Ctrl+f</kbd> for "copied comment") about the most copied comment on Stack Overflow.

| Comment Score | Total Copies | URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 938 | 4,924 | [How do you change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/#comment47852929) |

However the link doesn't seem to lead to a comment, or maybe that content has since been deleted.

What was the comment? Is there any way for regular users to see deleted comments?

Comment: *Is there any way for regular users to see deleted comments?* I suppose the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) might have grabbed a page while the subsequently deleted comment was still there.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[image: deleted comment: "plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))"]

The comment was deleted for giving the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/638443

Comment: Was the comment under the question, or under another answer?

Comment: Was under the question and was the first comment. That's probably why it was so copied. Ironically, it subverts the Q&A methodology

Comment: @Machavity it would be interesting to do a test to see if it's copied MORE as an answer now that the comment has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I guessed as much. Answering in comments is bad for many reasons, including defeating or subverting the voting / sorting mechanisms.  (Although sometimes it's better than nothing, as long as the answer actually is accurate and good.)  Sites like https://rpg.stackexchange.com/ make a much bigger deal about not answering in comments, because many of their questions require a long-form answer, and voting (and even correctness for some non-rules questions) is more subjective.  And because they have the moderator-time to question-volume to enforce it, at least on HNQ questions.

Comment: (Obviously *you* know that already, @Machavity, so I guess that was mostly for the benefit of future readers.  Who might want to read my answer in a comment, xD)